# Generate stub implementation from typelib

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, stub, typelib

I have a typelib file (`.tlb`) and I want to generate stub classes (preferably in C#) to **replace** the original typelib implementation eventually. It seems to me like there should be some tool for that job but I did not find anything.

Comment: About any decent decompiler can get that job done.  Like Reflector, ILSpy, etc.  Use tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library, decompile it and copy/paste the generated code.  Only do this when the COM component is stable or have your back to the wall because of a mistake in the author's IDL that can only be corrected with a manual edit.  Keep in mind that a type library never contains implementation, just declarations.

Comment: You already expanded your comment. Do you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: I much prefer not having to guess in an answer at the reason the question is asked.  Guessing does not make for great Q+A.